# How to use git hook pre-commit to stop commits to master

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I want to stop myself accidently commiting something to the master branch unless I am sure. So I tried this script to determine which branch I am on but there is a problem. When I create a new branch git name-rev returns master even though I am on the other branch

```
$ git branch
  ignore
  master
* set_support
$ git name-rev --name-only HEAD
master
```

This is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check to see if we are on master branch. Stop accidental commits
if [ "`git name-rev --name-only HEAD`" == "master" ]
then
   if [ -f i_want_to_commit_to_master ]
   then
      rm i_want_to_commit_to_master
      exit 0
   else
      echo "Cannot commit to master branch Adrian"
      echo "Remember to create file 'touch i_want_to_commit_to_master' to commit to master"
   fi
   exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

For Mark: I rebuilt git against latest stable tag and same results. It only works after a commit is made to the new branch.

```
$ mkdir gittest
$ cd gittest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/adrian/gittest/.git/
$ touch file1
$ git add file1
$ git commit
[master (root-commit) 7c56424] New file
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1
$ git branch
* master
$ git checkout -b new_branch
Switched to a new branch 'new_branch'
$ git name-rev --name-only HEAD
master
$ git --version
git version 1.7.7.1
$ git branch
  master
* new_branch
$ touch file2
$ git add file2
$ git commit
[new_branch 1e038fb] new file
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file2
$ git name-rev --name-only HEAD
new_branch
```

Comment: What version of git are you using, and on which operating system?  Those results from `git branch` followed by `git name-rev HEAD` look like a (surprising) bug, if you've really copied and pasted accurately.

Comment: I build git from source - last build was  $ git describe
v1.7.7-rc3
$ git --version
git version 1.7.7-rc3
$ uname -a
Linux iceweasel.bluedreamer 2.6.40.3-0.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 16 04:10:59 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This command is used to find a friendly name of a commit. What is happening is that HEAD is resolving to the sha1 of the commit first and then a name is determined. I'm guessing it is arbitrarily picking master for the name as it comes up first in what `git log --decorate` would come across.

I would just parse the output of `git branch` in your test:

```
"`git branch | grep \* | cut -f2 -d' '` == "master"
```

or a more direct way would be:

```
$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null) == "refs/heads/master"
```

Comment: Cool - Thanks Adam - I made a small change but it works now if [ "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)" == "refs/heads/master" ]

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative you could use `git rev-parse` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418022/813810). So the if expression would be:

```
"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == "master"
```