# git diff on date?

Tags: git

I'm accustomed to running a git comparison that will allow comparison with local git revs like:

```
git diff HEAD HEAD~110 -- some/file/path/file.ext
```

Is it possible to use the date instead? And if so, how? I would like to be able insert in place of the "110" in the above example, a date such as "4 Dec 2012".

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
git diff HEAD 'HEAD@{3 weeks ago}' -- some/file/path/file.ext
```

This is not, strictly speaking, the revision made three weeks ago. Instead, it's the position `HEAD` was at three weeks prior to the present. But it's probably close enough for your purposes - it will be very accurate if the current branch's `HEAD` moved forward steadily, as most tend to do. You can improve the accuracy by using a branch name instead of `HEAD`.

Instead of an offset-from-the-present, you can also use a date/time, like `HEAD@{1979-02-26 18:30:00}`. See `git help rev-parse`.

Comment: On ZSH I'm getting a failure of: `zsh: parse error near \`}'`  Any ideas as to what may be going on there?

Comment: `zsh` is trying to interpret the braces for you.  Quote them (double quotes around the whole thing, or backslash before each brace, or whatever).

Comment: Well, this doesn't really seem to work if you have a fresh checkout of a repository, my understanding is that the feature you quote is based on `git-reflog`, not on `git-log`.

Comment: full list of commits `git log --full-history --date=iso |grep Date`

Comment: As @cnst notes, this won't work with a fresh checkout. It will give the error "warning: Log for 'HEAD' only goes back to...". To resolve this, you can figure out the SHA you want to compare using like 

`git rev-list -1 --before="2016-03-27 12:00" master`

Comment: @JonathanStray maybe make that an answer?

Comment: Nice.  Just to chime in a bit, I was interested in diffing my current, changed, file to see how my current round of work had changed it and `git diff 'HEAD@{3 weeks ago}' --  mydir/myfile` did the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 26):

What you want must be this.

```
git diff HEAD '@{3 weeks ago}' -- some/file/path/file.ext
```

You should compare with `@{3 weeks ago}`, not `HEAD@{3 weeks ago}`.

What is difference?

If you were on another branch 3 weeks ago, `HEAD@{3 weeks ago}` would point the HEAD of the branch, on the other hand `@{3 weeks ago}` would point the HEAD of the current branch.

You can also explicitly name the branch.

```
git diff HEAD 'master@{3 weeks ago}' -- some/file/path/file.ext
```

Comment: warning: log for 'HEAD' only goes back to Mon, 22 May 2023 23:12:10 +0200

Answer (score 12):

Combining [Jonathan Stray's suggestion to use `git-rev-list --before`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658110/git-diff-on-date#comment62402663_9658178) to find the revision at a given date and [Show just the current branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417957/show-just-the-current-branch-in-git/1418022#1418022):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
  cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 DATE FILE...
git diff on FILE... since the specified DATE on the current branch.
EOF
  exit
fi

branch1=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
revision1=$(git rev-list -1 --before="$1" "$branch1")
shift

revision2=HEAD

git diff "$revision1" "$revision2" -- "$@"
```

Call this script with a date and optionally some file names, e.g.

```
git-diff-since yesterday
git-diff-since '4 Dec 2012' some/file/path/file.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

This command may help you.

```
git log --since="1 weeks ago" --name-only --pretty=format: some/file/path/
```

Or

```
import subprocess  
current_branch = subprocess.check_output(
    "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD", shell=True).strip()
revision1 = subprocess.check_output(
    "git rev-list -1 --before='{duration} ago' '{branch}' --".format(
        duration=duration, branch=current_branch), shell=True).strip()
content = subprocess.check_output(
    "git diff --name-only '{}' HEAD -- some/file/path".format(revision1), shell=True).strip()
```