# Find out previously pushed diff and logs in git repo

Tags: git, github

We have a git repo where we commit our code.
Is there a way to find out the diffs (and/or logs for the commit) previously committed say in a window of 1 day?

Branch-xyz
*Day-1*
(push diff-1) 
(push diff-2) 
*Day-2*
(push diff-3)
(push diff-4)
(push diff-5)

Is there a way to get all the logs for each commit by giving a window of date/time etc? 
My goal is to write a script which will send out an email by the end of the day everyday on what was committed (pushed) each day to the remote repo.

Comment: Is this a same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658110/git-diff-on-date

Comment: Hi, no. I want to get all the commits happened in the last, say 24 hours.

Comment: a list of commits (push to remote repo) happened in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of commits recent days, you can use `--since`.

```
git log --since=2018-12-17
```

To get it since yesterday,

```
git log --since=`date --date="1 day ago" '+%Y-%m-%d'`
```