# How to search github repository at a specific commit

Tags: github

Is there a way to search GitHub but constrain the search to a commit or range of commits. I often find myself navigating via blame or history to a specific commit, then wanting to search around the repo at this specific point in time:

[image]

I'm surprised I can't find any similar questions on SO, maybe I'm missing something obvious or its not possible?

I tried filtering by date but that seems to only operate on commits and won't show me any "Code" results

Comment: Could these feature requests be related? https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/8448 or https://github.com/sourcegraph/sourcegraph/issues/2307

Comment: If you can use git, this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658110/git-diff-on-date or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311494/how-to-get-git-to-show-commits-in-a-specified-date-range-for-author-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard/advanced search by adding `commit: 3A+a5494cb144af5d3b6d1854c2dbe3f3fae3050b2d`, for example:
https://github.com/search?q=commit%3A+a5494cb144af5d3b6d1854c2dbe3f3fae3050b2d&type=commits

Related? [How can I search for a commit message on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122628/how-can-i-search-for-a-commit-message-on-github)

`&type=code` also works, see https://github.com/cadamini/cadamini.github.io/search?q=regex&type=code but it doesn't seem to be available in the UI (simple/advanced search). You can click Code on the search results page or edit the URL.

Comment: This only seems to search for commits with a given SHA.  I want to search the repo (aka "&type=code") at a given commit

Comment: &type=code works but not the date range, in GitHub there is only the option to set specific dates in the advanced search. See my comments under your original post for further ideas/refs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe I am missing the obvious, but wouldn't a simple

```
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/fdcadfac43

-----------------------------------/tree/-----------
  (URL of the repo in question)             SHA
```

do the trick?
(Although, I have to admit I wouldn't know how to get there purely with mouse clicks.)

*PS:* Oh, and while we are on the subject of "browsing github at a point in time"... when you don't have a commit but know the date,  you can use `https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/HEAD@{2022-10-13}`

Comment: But the question is how do you search the rest of the codebase when you have that commit pulled up?  The search bar always seems to search the latest commit

Comment: Ah, ok. I re-read the question and apparently that is the "obvious" I was missing :) On my first read "search" translated to "browse the repo at that state".