# How do I determine what branch I have checked out in git?

Tags: git, branch, tagging

I clone my source using `git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git w/`. Then I specify a specific branch/tag by doing `git checkout <tag name>` or `git checkout origin/REL<release number>`. Sometimes I forget what branch I'm on.

In SVN I would do a `svn info` to figure out what branch I'm using.

**How do I determine what branch/tag I am on?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-do-i-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git branch
```

tells you what branch you're on (with a `*` marker).

Tags are just names for revisions, so Git won't tell you that you're "on" a tag, but you can use `git name-rev HEAD` to get a sense for what it might be.

Comment: `git branch` just gives me: `* (no branch)
  master`. BUT `git name-rev HEAD` does exactly what I want it to.

Comment: You get `(no branch)` because you're not "on a branch" anymore.  You have what git calls a "detached HEAD" (which, as someone noted, is rather graphic if you think about it :-) ).  Anyway, it's important to keep in mind that "being on a branch", in git terms, requires that you be at the *tip* of the branch.  Otherwise you're "detached".  If you add new commits when you're "detached", you create a new, unnamed branch.

Answer (score 5):

The current branch is marked with a `*` in the output of `git branch`.  Example:

```
$ git branch
  branch1
* branch2
  master
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I determine what branch/tag I am on?

First, [since Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088865/6309), you have `git branch --show-current` which directly shows you your current checked out branch.

Second, it won't show anything if you are in a checked out worktree ([created with `git worktree add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309))

For that, check Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), with its "`git branch --list`" which learned to show branches that are checked out in other worktrees connected to the same repository prefixed with '`+`', similar to the way the currently checked out branch is shown
with '`*`' in front.

Example:

[image: git branch in Git 2.23b4]

See [commit 6e93814](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e9381469e3bd866e73affe6d9d96206ee7ff965), [commit ab31381](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab3138146f9ce1d819cefab4515965604de76d9d), [commit 2582083](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2582083fa1830632e298727e973440907345267f) (29 Apr 2019) by [Nickolai Belakovski (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 99eea64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99eea645832d376a3b214b78a57adabf1fa96547), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `branch`: add `worktree` info on verbose output
>
> To display worktree path for refs checked out in a linked worktree

The [`git branch` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/99eea645832d376a3b214b78a57adabf1fa96547/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L29-L32) now states:

> The current branch will be highlighted in green and marked with an asterisk.
> **Any branches checked out in linked worktrees will be highlighted in cyan and marked with a plus sign.**

Answer (score 0):

If you use the bash shell, you [can use `__git_ps1` in your bash prompt](http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/2010/05/22/git-ps1.html) to show this, for example:

```
[me@myhost:~/code/myproject] (master)$ ls
```

Download [`git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) to `~/.git-completion.bash`

Then in your `~/.bashrc` file, add

```
source ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Then set your `PS1` value to something including `$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")`, something like:

```
PS1="[\u@\h:\w]\$(__git_ps1)\\$ "
```

Comment: per the comments in `git-completion.bash` I believe that function has been extracted to a dedicated script https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

Answer (score 0):

Some sed and regex magic:

```
git reflog | grep "checkout: moving from" | sed -n '1p' | sed -e 's/^[[:alnum:]]\+ HEAD@{[[:digit:]]\+}: checkout: moving from \([^[:space:]]\+\) to \([^[:space:]]\+\)$/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider using a nice prompt for your shell?
[Starship](https://github.com/starship/starship) for Bash or [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) for Zsh, or several superb ones are out there.
I'm in love with starship personally :)
https://github.com/CrazyOptimist/dotfiles
You will keep track of more than git branch info once you adopt one.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31759308)

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch
```

using this command tells you at what branch you are by an `*` marker.