# Output of git branch list and how is it determined?

Tags: git, git-branch

According to [the doc](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> If `--list` is given, or if there are no non-option arguments, existing branches are listed; the current branch will be highlighted with an asterisk.
>
> Option `-r` causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed,
>   and option `-a` shows both local and remote branches.
>
> If a `<pattern>` is
>   given, it is used as a shell wildcard to restrict the output to
>   matching branches. If multiple patterns are given, a branch is shown
>   if it matches any of the patterns. Note that when providing a
>   `<pattern>`, you must use `--list`;
>   otherwise, the command is interpreted as branch creation.

But what is not specified is what is the order of the listing.
Does `git branch -r --list  "$PATTERN"` output the branch name in some specified order?

Answer (score 1):

The output order is not affected by any pattern arguments.

The `git branch` command is a user-oriented interface layered atop [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html).<sup>1</sup>  The for-each-ref documentation describes the sorting in greater detail, but the `git branch` command's documentation includes this sub-description:

> Sort based on the key given. Prefix `-` to sort in descending order of the value. You may use the `--sort=<key>` option multiple times, in which case the last key becomes the primary key. The keys supported are the same as those in `git for-each-ref`. Sort order defaults to sorting based on the full refname (including `refs/...` prefix). **This lists detached HEAD (if present) first, then local branches and finally remote-tracking branches.**

(emphasis mine).  If your `git branch` porcelain front-end is too old to support `--sort` (pre-Git-2.7), you always get this default order.

---

<sup>1</sup>In some older versions of Git, there are things `git branch` can do that `git for-each-ref` cannot, so this is not strictly true in all versions of Git, it's just the way that the system has always been intended to work.  Newer versions of `git branch` support the `--sort` option that `git for-each-ref` has supported for longer.

Comment: Git 2.23 brings to `git branch --list` new sort options/behaviors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56978829/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57046734/6309

Comment: @VonC: the color for added work-trees' checked out branches is new; the fix to list detached HEAD first even in Chinese locales is, well, just a bug fix :-)

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to also says (under the documentation for the `--sort` option):

> Sort order defaults to sorting based on the full refname (including `refs/...` prefix). This lists detached HEAD (if present) first, then local branches and finally remote-tracking branches.

Comment: I put the link in—the OP might not have a Git new enough to have `--sort`.

Comment: Yes my `git branch --help` does not say anything about such an option