# bash script to check if the current git branch = "x"

Tags: git, bash, shell, sh

I am very bad at shell scripting (with bash), I am looking for a way to 
check if the current git branch is "x", and abort the script if it is not "x".

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    CURRENT_BRANCH="$(git branch)"
    if [[ "$CURRENT_BRANCH" -ne "master" ]]; then
          echo "Aborting script because you are not on the master branch."
          return;      # I need to abort here!
    fi

    echo "foo"
```

but this is not quite right

Comment: Given that your code is syntactically invalid, [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) should be your first recourse.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use [`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418022/112968) to get the name of the current branch.

Then it's only a matter of simply comparing values in your script:

```
BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
if [[ "$BRANCH" != "x" ]]; then
  echo 'Aborting script';
  exit 1;
fi

echo 'Do stuff';
```

Comment: Side note: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` is the right way for this case, where you want to get something back (and not an error) for if HEAD is currently detached.  To distinguish the detached HEAD case, use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` instead.

Comment: As a one liner: `[[ $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) == "master" ]] && echo "on master"`

Answer (score 7):

One option would be to parse the output of the `git branch` command:

```
BRANCH=$(git branch | sed -nr 's/\*\s(.*)/\1/p')

if [ -z $BRANCH ] || [ $BRANCH != "master" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

But a variant that uses git internal commands to get just the active branch name as suggested by @knittl is less error prone and preferable

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `exit` instead of `return`.

Answer (score 2):

With git 2 you can use a command easier to remember:

```
[[ $(git branch --show-current) == "master" ]] && echo "you are on master" || (echo "you are not on master"; echo "goodbye")
```

This is a one-liner version (notice the brackets on the last two commands to group them).