# Show information about only the current branch

Tags: git

`git branch -v` shows a very nice list of all branches with their refs and last commit title.  I would like to include that information (i.e. branch name, ref and commit title) in the log output from a script, but I only want it for the currently active branch.

Is there a way to get `git` to show me just the current branch?

Comment: If you really want the format of `git branch -v`, why not just grep for the branch name you desire? Do note that that output is for human consumption, not machine, and is subject to change. If you want something in particular, be more specific in your question. There are certainly better ways to go about this.

Comment: I want the branch name, ref number, and last commit title

Comment: With Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), you will have a simpler approach based on `git branch --show-current`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088865/6309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
git branch --list -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
git branch -v | grep -e "^*"
```

The `grep -e "^*"` term should filter out all branches except the current one, whose listing should start with an asterisk.