# How to set upstream branch to the same name as the branch

Tags: git

If I create a new branch and try to push it, I am told that I have to explicitly say what the name of the upstream branch needs to be.

```
> git checkout -b feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out
Switched to a new branch 'feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out'
> git push
fatal: The current branch feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out
```

Is there some way to do that without having to type out the name of the upstream branch?  I virtually *always* want it to be the same name on the server as it is locally.

Is there any way to do something like  `git push --set-upstream <current_branch_name>`, independent of what the current branch name happens to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the best version of the responses but was buried [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446481/6136235) by [@Good Night Nerd Pride](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025555/good-night-nerd-pride)

```
git config --global alias.pushnew 'push -u origin HEAD'
```

Explanation:

1. `push -u origin HEAD` Is the shorter way to push up the current branch name to the remote upstream.
2. `git config --global alias.pushnew` sets it so that when you run `git push` it will set the upstream as we did in #1.

And combine with the [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446061/6136235) from [@Sajib Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4133798/sajib-khan):

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Answer (score 36):

Configure git config

```
$ git config --global push.default current
```

Now, after checkout to a branch, you should use simply `git push`

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
$ git push                    # similar to git push -u origin new-branch
```

---

If you want to set upstream for the future then use `--set-upstream` (-u) flag:

```
$ git push -u origin HEAD
```

**N.B.** HEAD and local current branch normally stay in the same state.

Comment: This answer should not be voted higher than the accepted answer as it does not do what OP asked for. It [does not do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446481/1025555) `git push --set-upstream <current_branch_name>`.

Answer (score 18):

[Edit] [sajib khan's first answer, setting `push.default` to `current`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446061/1256452) will enable pushing, but does not actually set the upstream.  This means that after a future `git fetch`, your Git won't report ahead/behind counts, and your Git won't know the upstream to use for `git rebase` or `git merge` (or `git pull` either though I advise avoiding `git pull`).

You can use [edit, as in the second part of his answer]:

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

If needed, this creates the branch on the other Git, so that your Git acquires the `origin/` variant.  Then in any case it sets that (maybe new) remote-tracking branch you have as your branch's upstream.  But until `origin/feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out` actually *exists*, you can't set it as the upstream.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, you *can*, you just can't use `git branch --set-upstream` to do it.  And, you don't want to type it in again anyway.  To do it "manually" you would need:

```
git config \
  branch.feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out.remote origin
git config \
  branch.feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out.merge \
  feature/long-branch-name-I-dont-want-to-have-to-type-out
```

which means typing it out three times (!), or writing yourself a script.

Comment: So essentially you would want to do something like this: `git config --global alias.pushnew 'push -u origin HEAD'`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: that (the `git push` I mean, not the alias) is in fact a command I run myself at times. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's some handy git commands that can help out here.

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` -> returns the current branch name

`git branch -u <remote>/<branch>` -> sets the current branch to track `<remote>/<branch>`

I do this sort of thing a lot and leverage aliases to help me out.

```
alias gph='git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
alias gbuh='git branch -u origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

Reference:

- OG answers on getting the name of the current branch [newer post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/3234235) and [OG post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418022/3234235)