# Copy a file in bash renaming its target with current date and current (checked out) git branch name

Tags: git, bash

For workflow purposes I would like to write a bash script where I copy a file renaming it with the current date and current git branch name in its target, like this:

```
$ cp test.txt test-$(date +'%Y-%h-%d')-$(__git_ps1).txt
```

Say I'm in a branch named `feature`, the output file name would be (date of today):

```
test-2017-Nov-5-feature.txt
```

For the date part (`2017-Nov-5`), it works fine, but I'm having difficulties to output it along with the current git branch name via `$(__git_ps)`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: it's not rare that branch names come with a `/`. how are you going to handle that?

Comment: What is the difficulty you mentioned?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr 's comment is absolutely right and I should rethink that. @janos, bash shows me the correct usage of `cp` in the output, as though the `__git_ps1` generates a space in the `target_file`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417957/show-just-the-current-branch-in-git or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ANSWER:

the problem with your command is the leading space produced by `__git_ps1`.

You can delete all spaces for example with the following command:

```
cp test.txt test-$(date +'%Y-%h-%d')-$(__git_ps1 | tr -d '[:space:]').txt
```

In this way however the output still contains the '(' and ')' that I thought you didn't want (see alternative solution)

#### NOTE

the possible 'slash in branch name' problem (highlighted by [@HuStmpHrrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3040064/hustmphrrr)) can be solved in a similar way, by deleting (like done with spaces) or traslating to compatible character  ( `| tr '/' '_'`)

#### output

normal

> test-2017-Nov-06-(master).txt

if the detached working space

> test-2017-Nov-06-((2af977d...)).txt

### ALTERNATIVE COMMAND:

try using

```
cp test.txt test-$(date +'%Y-%h-%d')-$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).txt
```

#### output

normal

> test-2017-Nov-06-master.txt

if the detached working space

> test-2017-Nov-06-HEAD.txt

Comment: thank you! just a note on the first answer: I had to delete one pipe (before `tr`) and the current branch was outputted like I wanted, thank you again