# Cannot suppress git branch error when not in a git repository

Tags: bash, git

I would like my command prompt to display the current branch in my Prompt String 1 (PS1). The command works in git repositories, but when not in a git repo, I get the rightful error message: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I would like to suppress that error message otherwise every time I switch directories and I am not in a git repo, that error is printed to the terminal.

I read up on suppressing terminal output by sending error output to the null device `/dev/null`, but the error message still prints in my terminal.

Here is the command I am using to extract the current branch:

`git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | cut -d ' ' -f2`.

Comment: How are you setting PS1, ~.bashrc? Please add details to your question.

Comment: I am setting it in my `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to escape the `$` in the `$()` construct, so that it will be evaluated anew when each prompt is generated instead of only when the PS1 variable is set.

Here's what it looks like for me in practice:

```
# Set PS1
$ PS1="\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2) $ "

# Currently in directory that is not a Git repository, change into one.
 $ cd dotfiles/

# Git branch is then displayed in the prompt, leave the directory.
master $ cd ..

# No git branch displayed, change back into it for good measure.
 $ cd dotfiles/

# Branch is displayed again.
master $
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about escaping dollar signs to do a new evaluation upon variable retrieval. Is there a specific term for this feature in bash-speak? Strangely enough, starting my computer this morning and running the same command on my terminal is no longer throwing the error, so redirection to the null device seems to be working as expected today.,, Or I dunno what was happening :P

Comment: I'm not aware of a name. It's just a matter of reasoning about when and how the string is processed. If, for example, you wanted to display a literal "$(...)", you'd have to escape the escape character too `\\\$(...)`. That way, by the time the shell is presenting the prompt, it's encountering `\$(...)`.