# What's the best alias for not having to remember the branch I'm in to pull and push?

Tags: linux, bash, git, scripting

Extremely lazy here, don't like to type too much and specially don't like to remember on which branch I'm in to pull from and push to. Far too often I make the mistake of doing `git pull` from a non-master branch, or worse do a push and the target branch is incorrect and I'm left with un-pushed or uncommitted changes.

I created in my `.bashrc` the following aliases to help:

```
alias gitr='git status | grep -Po "On branch \K[^ ]+" | xargs git push origin'
```

So doing `gitr` on any git repo will push the committed changes to the correct branch.

Likewise doing:

```
alias gitp='git status | grep -Po "On branch \K[^ ]+" | xargs git pull origin'
```

will pull the latest changes from the correct branch I'm currently in.

Finally this one will commit all local changes as "Cosmetics" and push them to the correct branch:

```
alias gitcr='git commit -a -m "Cosmetics" && git status | grep -Po "On branch \K[^ ]+" | xargs git push origin'
```

Is there a way to print all the intermediate commands without doing print in each? and is there a way to make these commands more robust?

**UPDATE** by print the intermediate commands I mean to show the following to be sure it is running the correct commands:

```
git status
git pull origin somebranch
```

Comment: Configure your shell to show the current branch in its prompt. Example: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e0f78f0d478987c0443fcf9f7274cde.webp

Comment: `xargs -t` will print what it's doing, though perhaps that's too late for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least, [with Git 2.22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088865/6309), you can use:

```
git branch  --show-current
```

That would avoid a few grep/awk/sed

Plus, if you want to *push*, you need the name of the remote tracking branch associated to the current branch (you could have associated the remote 'bar' branch to your local 'foo' branch'

That is [`[<branchname>]@{push}`, e.g. `master@{push}, @{push}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem)

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{push}|cut -d / -f 2
```

Again The suffix `@{push}` reports the branch "where we would push to" if `git push` were run while branchname was checked out.

Note: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{push}|cut -d / -f 1` will give you the name of the remote, which is *not* always `origin`.

It is *not* the same as `[<branchname>]@{upstream}`, e.g. `master@{upstream}`, `@{u}`.
The suffix `@{upstream}` to a `branchname` (short form `<branchname>@{u}`) refers to the branch that the branch specified by `branchname` is set to build on top of (configured with `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`).
Ie the branch you are *pulling* from.

See "[Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720302/6309)" for the Git 2.5+ `@{push}` shortcut notation.

---

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) clarifies the `@{upstream}` shortcut.

See [commit 8cdab69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8cdab69d967ec826ed258e31a26c8cb4720ffdca) (23 Jun 2022) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9a13943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a13943ef4e671235cacef7d1612c8765d1312a9), 13 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8cdab69d967ec826ed258e31a26c8cb4720ffdca): documentation adjustment - mention remote tracking with `@{u}`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>

> The documentation explained the conversion from remote branch path to local tracking ref path for `@{push}`, but not for `@{upstream}`.
>
> Add the explanation to `@{upstream}`, and reference it in `@{push}` to avoid undue repetition.

`revisions` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8cdab69d967ec826ed258e31a26c8cb4720ffdca/Documentation/revisions.txt#L99-L102):

> A branch `B` may be set up to build on top of a branch `X` (configured with
> `branch.<name>.merge`) at a remote `R` (configured with
> `branch.<name>.remote`).
>
> `B@{u}` refers to the remote-tracking branch for
> the branch `X` taken from remote `R`, typically found at `refs/remotes/R/X`.

Comment: Thanks! good to know but my most up to date Ubuntu 18.04.02 shows `git version 2.17.1`

Comment: @SkyWalker You can upgrade it easily enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309

Answer (score 1):

You can set git aliases in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    p=!git status && git pull origin $(git branch | sed 's/.* //')
    r=!git status && git push origin $(git branch | sed 's/.* //')
```

Usage:

```
$ git branch
  master
* other
$ git p
On branch other
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/other'.
```

Comment: Thanks! how do you use them? the same as the OP aliases?

Answer (score 1):

To quickly display only current branch name you can use :

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a [tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) and set [push.default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault) to 'upstream' or similar then `git pull`/`git push` without arguments will default to that branch.

To set 'push.default' run `git config --global push.default upstream`.

If you originally pulled the branch from a remote then a tracking branch should have been created automatically. If you created the branch locally then you can create a tracking branch by including the `-u` option when you push:

```
git push -u <remote> <branch>
```

Comment: True, see my edited answer. I do address the right branch name to use when pushing.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `git-prompt` to solve this problem. Besides my hostname and current path, my prompt always shows what branch I'm on, so it's immediately obvious what I'm about to push.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh