# Change variable based on current stage

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gitlab, serverless, staging

I have Serverless application that has two stages: develop (on branch develop) and master (on branch master).
It has a file called config.js like this:

```
API_URL: api.prod.some-server.com
```

But I want that "prod" changed to "dev" when I'm on `develop` branch / on develop stage environment.
It's kinda exhausting if I should change the API_URL back-and-forth (prod -> dev) when I changed the current branch/dev_stage.

Is there any possible to automate this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possible to automate this?

Yes: You would need to *not* version [`config.js`](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) (keep it private), but to *generate* it (with the right value in it).

The generation script will determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Or (since [Git 2.22, Q2 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088865/6309))

```
branch=$(git branch --show-current)
```

That means you could:

- version only a template file `config.js.tpl`
- version value files named after the branches: `config.js.dev`, `config.js.master`: since they are different, there is no merge issue when merging or switching branches.

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated to the template file (`config.js.tpl`), would generate (automatically, on `git checkout`) the actual `config.js` file by looking values in the right `config.js.<branch>` value file.
The generated actual `config.js` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".