# List all configuration entries in section with git config

Tags: git, git-config

Is there a direct way to list all key/value pairs in a section with `git config`? E.g., to list all entries under the `core` section.

I'm using `git config --get-regexp <section-name>`, but it seems kind of dumb—why use a regexp when I simply want all of the entries in a section.

On a related note, is there a way to list all configuration entries of the current checked out branch, without having to type in the name of the branch? (I.e. `git config --get-regexp branch\.<branch-name>\.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088865/6309) `git branch --show-current`, you can use:

```
git config --get-regexp branch\.$(git branch --show-current)\.
```

But a regexp remain the way to list a config section.

Example:

```
vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git/git (master)
$ git config --get-regexp branch\.$(git branch --show-current)\.
branch.master.remote origin
branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
branch.master.pushremote master next
```