# Github doesn't displays the branch name next to the workflow run of manually run workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

Does anyone know how to view the branch name? Even on manually run workflows?
Can't see any obvious settings to change it.

*** EDIT ***

Here's how it looks in most repositories (with the branch name in blue):

[image]

And here's the exception repo with no branch name link:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide the workflow files for each?

Answer (score -1):

To display the current branch you're on, without the other branches listed, you can do the following:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Reference:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417957/show-just-the-current-branch-in-git/1418022#1418022)

or with Git 2.22 and above:

```
git branch --show-current
```

Comment: that's not what I meant. I will edit the post

Comment: Hey, I don't understand what do you mean but i will try. you just want to see your branches? or somewhere specifically? only on manually run workflows?
Because on **<> code** you can see how much branches and when you click on it you can see all branches (near tags)