# Get the name of the current git branch with PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, github

I would like to be able to do git commands from a PowerShell script which is not located in the same folder as my git repo.

First I want to check the current branch, and if it's not master try to checkout master and pull master.

What I've done so far:

```cs
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$currentPath = Get-ScriptDirectory
[string]$Path_GIT = "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe"
$gitRepo = $currentPath + "\..\"
$nameCurrentBranch = & $Path_GIT git -C "$gitRepo" rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

From the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git).

`$gitRepo` contains the path of the folder containing the git repo.

I get the error:

```
git-cmd.exe : fatal: Cannot change to 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Projects\MyProject\
Batchs\.." rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD': Invalid argument
At C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Projects\MyProject\Batchs\Publish.ps1:64 char:22
+ ... entBranch = & $Path_GIT git -C "$gitRepo" rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Cannot c...nvalid argument:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

**EDIT:** New problem after the proposition of @4c74356b41 (using `Join-Path`):
I don't have any error a popup opens and close really fast and then my powershell script is stuck, as if it was waiting for the git-cmd.exe to close. But I can't see the windows of the cmd git and can't close it.

Comment: Are you aware of Posh Git? https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

Comment: posh-git wouldn't help in any way shape or form

Comment: Reading your code example, you are already in your repo. That means posh-git would help like mentioned by @Mark. (e.g. `Get-GitDirectory`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display my current git branch name in my PowerShell prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287718/how-can-i-display-my-current-git-branch-name-in-my-powershell-prompt)

Comment: If one uses posh-git, would one not then need to install it also on every server and developer machine where the PS-script should be run? Ok for personal use, but...

Answer (score 26):

CD Your repository folder

```
$branch= &git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

## from [Show just the current branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417957/show-just-the-current-branch-in-git/1418022#1418022)

Comment: This gets some extra info, for me this works better `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD --)[0]`

Comment: As of git 2.22 this is a little bit simpler `$branch = git branch --show-current`

Answer (score 1):

Try Join-Path

```
$gitRepo = Join-Path $currentPath ".." -Resolve
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know have a new error (i've tried with and without the quotes around $gitRepo in the call of git-cmd.

Comment: why do you want to execute that command in the root of the repo?

Comment: To get the name of the current branch. If it's not master I want to checkout master and pull master.

Comment: so why not just checkout master and pull it? checkout to master would do no bad if you are on master @user2088807 also, why not just use `git status -b`

Answer (score 0):

Use psget to install the posh-git plugin that shows you the current branch. If you have the latest powershell, chances are that psget is already installed. If you dont have it then get it by using this command.

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
```

To install posh-git use the command:

```
Install-Module posh-git
```