# Show current branch on terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to show in `Terminal` of `VS Code` to show in brackets `current branch`? I saw it somewhere but not sure how it can be done. By some extension or whatever..

```
C:/myUser/project> git status
```

I would like to see it something like:

```
C:/myUser/project>(master) git status
```

Comment: if you use Git Bash it should be automatically there.

Answer (score 1):

Open ~/.zshrc in an editor of your choice.

```shrc
nano ~/.zshrc
```

**Add this text in the end of zshrc file**

```shrc
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() { vcs_info }
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats 'on branch %b'
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%n in ${PWD/#$HOME/~} ${vcs_info_msg_0_} > '
```

**Source zshrc file**

Reload your .zshrc (or restart your terminal)

```shrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.The question was on a Windows OS. Your answer looks as it explains how to do on a UNIX OS.

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux Terminal**

You can modify the PS1 variable. PS1 is a Bash Environment Variable that represents the primary prompt string which is displayed when the shell is ready.
You can achieve your result by modifying this variable with a script.
First, get the output of your current value of the variable by running

```
$ echo $PS1
```

Sample output:`[\u@\h \W]$`

Now you save the following code in a bash file(Remember to replace the initial string of export PS1 with the output of the above command).

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
get_cur_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
 }
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$(get_cur_branch)\$ "
```

Let's say path of the file is "/home/samar/Documents/my_vs_script.sh"

Now change your VS code settings by adding the following lines in 'settings.json'

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
"--init-file",
"/home/samar/Documents/my_vs_script.sh"
]
```

Now each time you open a new terminal in VS code, script file "my_vs_script.sh" will execute and you get the desired output.

**For Windows-Powershell**

The solution above works well for the Linux terminal. But if you want to do it for another command-line shell-like Powershell, you can change the 'setting.json' to

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-NoExit",
    "-Command", "c:/scripts/myscript.ps1"
  ]
}
```

where 'myscript.ps1' must have a function 'prompt' definition to add git branch to your prompt.

You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287718/how-can-i-display-my-current-git-branch-name-in-my-powershell-prompt/10106906) for your 'myscript.ps1' code.
You don't need to change 'Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'. Defining it in another file works too.

I hope it helps.