# How can we show branch name anytime we’re running terminal on git directory in windows?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, windows-terminal

The branch name is shown in git bash, but in my vs code, the branch name does not show. 
I want the branch name to be shown in PowerShell as it is my default terminal in vs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install posh-git: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

You could also have a look at this tutorial: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-make-a-pretty-prompt-in-windows-terminal-with-powerline-nerd-fonts-cascadia-code-wsl-and-ohmyposh

Comment: Is there any way to do this by configuring PowerShell? Does PowerShell support plugins for this kind of purpose

Comment: @KnowledgeMan https://stackoverflow.com/q/1287718/6309 should help.